# Completed time reporting by previous dates in TFS

Tags: reporting, scheduling, tfs-2015

I wanted to know is there is possibility to configure TFS 2015 to allow people to report Completed works in previous dates. By default it is possible to report only with system date (today), but sometimes there is need of time reporting about yesterday or day before etc.

TFS Version: 2015 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, tfs does not support that. If you want to manage dates for completed work you may create a new work item type (like Timesheet) with [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) and use it for time reporting. In this case your work will be more complex because

1. developers have to create a new work item for time reporting and link it to task
2. you have to sum time for task with custom tool (like [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GiulioVian.TFSAggregator))
3. you have to update your reports to use a new work item type.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of extensions that support real time tracking in TFS plus a number rif tools that can sync across from TFS to another tool.

Examples:

- http://www.tfs-timetracker.com/
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shkleinik.TXChronoTFSTimesheet
- https://www.teamexpand.com/
- Microsoft Project

The time tracking in TFS itself is very limited as it isn't meant for record keeping, but simply to support forecasting and planning.

The common recommendation is to separate the detailed time tracking from your planning systems. It helps people with techniques like relative estimation and disconnects our brain from the clock (trying to convert everything into hours or minutes).